# kendo ui grid row how to set background color?

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to change the row color of a kendo ui grid depending on a particular condition.  I am using server side bindings with MVC.  My code is as follows,

```
var grid = Html.Kendo().Grid<AllocateCOESGridViewModel>();
grid.Name("AllocateResultGrid")
.RowAction(row =>
{
   if (row.DataItem.COESNo == 13054915)
   {
       row.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background:blue";
   }
   else
   {
       row.HtmlAttributes["style"] = "background:red";
   }                
})  
.Columns(columns =>
{   
    columns.Bound(s => s.COESNo).Title(@Allocate.COESGridHeading);                  
    columns.Bound(s => s.Street).Title(@Allocate.StreetGridHeading);
    columns.Bound(s => s.Suburb).Title(@Allocate.SuburbGridHeading);
    columns.Bound(s => s.Postcode).Title(@Allocate.PostcodeGridHeading);
    columns.Bound(s => s.InspectorName).Title(@Allocate.InspectorGridHeading);
    columns.Bound(s => s.COESNo).Title(@Allocate.AllocateGridHeading + "<input type ='checkbox' id ='SelectAll'  />").ClientTemplate("<input type ='checkbox' data-id='#= COESNo #' class='allocate' />").Sortable(false);
});
```

The grid works but no row colors at all? no blue or red.. I just get the standard white and grey.. any thoughts?

Thanks

This is how I got this to work, just wondering if there is any other options, as looping through the grid seems like a not so good idea... especially if the grid is long

```
 var grid = $("#AllocateResultGrid").data("kendoGrid");
 grid.bind("dataBound", updateGridRows);

 updateGridRows: function()
{
    dataView = this.dataSource.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) 
    {
        if (dataView[i].Selected == false) 
        {
            var uid = dataView[i].uid;
            $("#AllocateResultGrid tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]").addClass("customClass");
        }
    }

}
```

I added the customClass in my stylesheet

Comment: What happens when you break in the debugger inside RowAction?

Comment: it doesn't break in it... now one thing I just realised is I am getting the data for the grid through a datasource... I have updated the code above

Comment: would the RowAction work? as I am using ajax to get the data

Comment: I actually got this to work by binding the databound event of the grid.  It works but it involves looping through the grid, my current grid has 1200 entries, so it takes a bit more time to render the grid.  Is there another way to achieve this?  (see my updated code above)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, let me know if you find one without loops!

```
var grid = $("#AllocateResultGrid").data("kendoGrid");
var data = grid.dataSource.data();
$.each(data, function (i, row) {
  if (row.Selected == false)
     $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ').addClass("customClass");
}
```